# multi group sum

Tags: mysql, group-by

Below is my payments mysql 5.7.9 table need help to write a query

payments

```
|s.no          |transaction   |order-id      |order-item-code|amount-type      |amount
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1             |Order         |1             |11             |ItemPrice        |200
|2             |Order         |1             |11             |ItemPrice        |100
|3             |Order         |1             |11             |ItemFees         |-12
|4             |Order         |1             |11             |ItemFees         |-1.74
|5             |Order         |1             |11             |ItemFees         |-10
|6             |Order         |1             |11             |ItemFees         |-1.45
|7             |Order         |1             |11             |ItemFees         |-4
|8             |Order         |1             |11             |ItemFees         |-0.58
|9             |Order         |1             |22             |ItemPrice        |150
|10            |Order         |1             |22             |ItemPrice        |50
|11            |Order         |1             |22             |ItemFees         |-12
|12            |Order         |1             |22             |ItemFees         |-1.74
|13            |Order         |1             |22             |ItemFees         |-10
|14            |Order         |1             |22             |ItemFees         |-1.45
|15            |Order         |1             |22             |ItemFees         |-4
|16            |Order         |1             |22             |ItemFees         |-0.58
|17            |Ship          |1             |               |other-transaction|-55
|18            |Ship Tax      |1             |               |other-transaction|-7.98
|19            |Order         |2             |33             |ItemPrice        |450
|20            |Order         |2             |33             |ItemPrice        |150
|21            |Order         |2             |33             |ItemFees         |-36
|22            |Order         |2             |33             |ItemFees         |-5.22
|23            |Order         |2             |33             |ItemFees         |-30
|24            |Order         |2             |33             |ItemFees         |-4.35
|25            |Order         |2             |33             |ItemFees         |-12
|26            |Order         |2             |33             |ItemFees         |-1.74
|27            |Ship          |2             |               |other-transaction|-55
|28            |Ship Tax      |2             |               |other-transaction|-7.98
```

Expected result

```
    |order-id       |order-item-code     |Received
    ---------------------------------------------
    |1              |11                  |238.74
    |1              |22                  |138.74
    |2              |33                  |447.71
```

Calculation Logic:

sum (itemprice per order-item-code) + sum(itemfees per order-item-code) + sum (other-transaction per order-id) / distinct of order-item-id in  order-id

other transaction is the shipping fee charged on a order, I need to divide the sum of other transactions with no of unique items present in the order.
in case of order-id- 1, we have 2 items as only two item id code, in case of order-id -2 we have one item. it is the no of distinct order-item -code present

Comment: I'm not getting the numbers you're getting with the formula you're giving, for example with order 1 order item code 11 I get `300 - 29.77 - 62.98/2` = 238.74.

Comment: @ sagi made two select statements need to loin & sum them  `SELECT `order-id`, COUNT(DISTINCT `order-item-code`) as itemcount
FROM payments
GROUP BY `order-id`` and `SELECT `order-item-code`, SUM(payments.amount),`order-id`
  FROM payments
GROUP BY `order-item-code``

Comment: @Kanted Are the empty order-item-code fields NULL or an empty string?

Comment: @ Joachim Isaksson empty string

Comment: Do not use '-' in a table/column identifier

Answer (score 0):

You can use a joined subquery so that you can use two separate `GROUP BY`.

The subquery calculates the "other transactions" (summing them up and dividing by the number of order_item_codes), and the outer query does a normal sum of the per code entries, just adding its part of the common transactions;

```
SELECT p.order_id, p.order_item_code, SUM(p.amount) + z.other AS received
FROM payments p
JOIN (
  SELECT order_id, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN order_item_code = ''
             THEN amount 
             ELSE 0.0 END) / (COUNT(DISTINCT order_item_code) - 1) AS other 
  FROM payments
  GROUP BY order_id
) z
ON p.order_id = z.order_id
GROUP BY p.order_id, p.order_item_code
HAVING order_item_code <> ''
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a72a4/1).

Note that this query may fail if there are "other transaction" entries on an order_id that has no item codes, since the inner query will attempt to allocate the common cost to zero codes. If you need this to work, you'll need to work out what the correct result in that case would be.

EDIT: If the order-item_id is NULL, the query changes a little;

```
SELECT p.order_id, p.order_item_code, SUM(p.amount) + z.other AS received
FROM payments p
JOIN (
  SELECT order_id, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN order_item_code IS NULL
             THEN amount 
             ELSE 0.0 END) / (COUNT(DISTINCT order_item_code)) AS other 
  FROM payments
  GROUP BY order_id
) z
ON p.order_id = z.order_id
GROUP BY p.order_id, p.order_item_code
HAVING order_item_code IS NOT NULL
```

Note the change of comparisons to `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL` as well as removing the `-1` at the count since the empty string *is* counted while `NULL` is not.

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22a85/1).

Comment: @ Joachim Isaksson thanks for your input just now found that the order-item-id is null incase of shipping. Got all values as Null . tried replacing `CASE WHEN order_item_code is null` still no luck

Comment: @Kanted Added an alternative.